# How to exclude search results that match a URL instead of the content of the URL

Tags: google-search, search-engines, bing

Is there a way to tell major search engines to ignore search results where the matching phrase is in the URL itself and not the content of the URL?

This came up while thinking about [The First Number Not In Google](http://godplaysdice.blogspot.com/2008/09/first-number-not-in-google.html). If I search for *454557414* on Google, this is what I see. 
[image: Google Search For 454557414]

Is there any way to exclude results like the first one circled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a search for: [454557414 -inurl:454557414](https://www.google.pl/search?q=454557414+-inurl:454557414+)

Answer (score 4):

Try excluding `inurl:`

```
454557414 -inurl:454557414
```

`inurl` includes

`-inurl` excludes

Is this what you were looking for?